# In djangocms template, how to make link editable from frontend?

Tags: jinja2, django-cms

I'm working through the [Divio Django CMS Tutorial](http://support.divio.com/academy/guide-how-to-build-a-website-and-blog-with-django-cms/7-adding-content). At one point a static link is provided in the template:

```
            <a href="#">
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-github fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
              </span>
            </a>
```

(base.html) and I would like to edit this link from the CMS frontend. So I'm trying something like:

```
            {% placeholder "githublink" %}
            <a href="#">
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-github fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
              </span>
            </a>
            {% endplaceholder %}
```

and adding a Link plugin in the frontend, but I keep getting a TemplateSyntax Error.

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach would work if it was a [static placeholder](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/introduction/templates_placeholders.html#static-placeholders) you were using. They're best suited to site headers/footers and allow you to include the same markup in all templates, which when edited in one place will show the content everywhere the placeholder is included. You can specify default content between the start & end tags similar to what you've done there.

However with what you're asking, I think a custom template & the `djangocms_link` plugin will work best. So you might just include `{% placeholder "links" %}` in a template. Which renders a placeholder & you could add link plugins to that.

You could then include a custom template to render your links with your own markup & specify that template when creating the plugins. Create a template;

`templates/djangocms_link/fa-markup/link.html`

```
        <a href="{{ link }}"{% if instance.target %} target="{{ instance.target }}"{% endif %}>
          <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
            <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-github fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
          </span>
        </a>
```

Then add the template to your settings;

```
DJANGOCMS_LINK_TEMPLATES = [
    ('fa-markup', _('Font Awesome Version')),
]
```

Comment: I'll try as soon as I get my django cms instance running again.